# Luarocks error building luafilesystem

Tags: lua, mingw, luarocks

I'm using **Luarocks 2.2.0beta1** to install **luafilesystem** on windows 7 with **lua 5.2** and **mingw**. I got this error:

```
>luarocks install luafilesystem
Installing http://rocks.moonscript.org/luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.src.rock...
Using http://rocks.moonscript.org/luafilesystem-1.6.2-2.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/lfs.o -IC:/lua/include/src/lfs.c
mingw32-gcc -shared -o lfs.dll src/lfs.o C:/lua/bin/lua52.dll -lm
C:\lua\bin\lua52.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: Id returned 1 exit status

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module lfs.dll
```

any idea how to fix this?

note: until now, I have no problem installing other module with luarocks that have no dependency with luafilesystem.

Comment: What is just before those lines?

Comment: Could be a 32bit-64bit issue. Did you compile `lua52.dll` yourself using the same MinGW compiler as you are trying to use now?

Comment: @EtanReisner I've writes the full text now

Comment: @siffiejoe yes, I compiled it using the same mingw compiler. I've tried using dll from other compiler and it doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, this problem arise because actually I'm not using the same MinGW compiler when building `lua52.dll`. I don't know which compiler I use at the first time. Thanks to @siffiejoe

Comment: Note, you can use something like CFF Explorer or any PE binary parser(eg. objdump, nm, or dumpbin) to identify the dll's bit format.